# Nuclear powered flux compression generator?

Tags: magnetic-fields, nuclear-physics

A [flux compression generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_pumped_flux_compression_generator) is a device for converting the chemical energy of explosives into magnetic field energy, with reported efficiencies of up to 20%. Is there a limit on the conversion efficiency or size of such a device, and especially could a fission bomb pump a similar device with such high efficiency conversion? I am thinking here of the mechanism similar to that used to trigger fission to fusion by [radiation implosion](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Library/Teller.html) in a thermonuclear bomb.

Comment: When things are at the temperature of a fission bomb, everything becomes a plasma and thus a good conductor. I suspect that will mess with your mechanism, but this is not my area... and I hope you too are asking just out of curiosity and not because you are hoping for detailed drawings!

Comment: Well, I've got the nuclear bomb and was wondering what interesting stuff I could do with it...

Comment: Yeah - I pretty much figured you were auditioning for the next Bond movie. And not for the part of 007.

Comment: You can certainly petition the US government for such an experiment... but I doubt they will bail out of the nuclear test ban treaty to let you have a classified paper that can't be published anyway... anyway, credits for the suggestion, blowing up stuff in the name of science is always cool.

Comment: I suspect the US govt might have already tried the experiment, which is one reason for the question